# How to pass int value from method to main()

Tags: java, methods, return

i want to ask about my java code, how to return int value from method to main() for display as print from main(), here the code i write but cannot print from main():

```
    package salaryemp;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class SalaryEmp {
int hour_rate, normal, overt, t_normal, t_overt, all_t, otpr;


SalaryEmp(int x,int z, int r){
hour_rate =  x;
normal = z;
overt = r;
}

void Weekcount(){
otpr = (hour_rate/2)+hour_rate;
t_normal = normal*hour_rate;
t_overt = overt*otpr;
all_t = (t_normal + t_overt);  

//Dont want print from this method, i want print from main()
//System.out.println("Your salary for this week is RM: " + t_normal );
//System.out.println("Your salary for this week is RM: " + t_overt );
//System.out.println("Your salary for this week is RM: " + all_t );   

}


public static void main(String[] args) {

       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       int hourrate, tworkingh, tovertt;
       System.out.print("Insert hourly rate RM: ");
       hourrate = input.nextInt();
       System.out.print("Insert Total working hour : ");
       tworkingh = input.nextInt();
       System.out.print("Insert Total overtime hour : ");
       tovertt = input.nextInt();
       SalaryEmp s1 = new SalaryEmp(hourrate, tworkingh, tovertt);

       s1.Weekcount();

       //*Print result here

   }
}
```

i new in java hope, can help me give some example or advices

Comment: Call the method and assign its return value (make it return something) to some variable in the `main`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The method interacts with fields and returns `void`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make `Weekcount()` return type as `int`

```
int Weekcount()
{
  otpr = (hour_rate/2)+hour_rate;
  t_normal = normal*hour_rate;
  t_overt = overt*otpr;
  return (t_normal + t_overt); 
 }
```

and call it from `main()` like this.

```
   int weekCount = s1.Weekcount();
   System.out.println(weekCount);
```